# Form newline issue

Tags: php, javascript

I am sending a form with a notes field to an Oracle database and then displaying the notes. New notes can be added, and they will be appended to the previous note.

The problem I have is with the newline that I am inserting at the beginning of each notes update. I am sending notes updates to the database with a javascript in this manner: `oldNote + "\n" + date + " " + username + ": " + newNote;`.

This is the php part:

```
echo "<input class='button' type='button' id='Save' name='saveInteraction' onclick=\"saveInteractionInfo('$oldNote', '$date', '$username', '$interactionId', '$seqNum');\" value='Update'/>";
```

This is the entire javascript function:

```
function saveInteractionInfo(oldNote, date, username, interactionId, seqNum) {
    var formData = {};
    formData['interactionId'] = interactionId;
    formData['seqNum'] = seqNum;
    formData['notes'] = oldNote + "\n" + date + " " + username + ": " + document.all.notes.value;
    trxId = readCookie("transactionId");
    if(trxId)
        formData["transactionId"] = trxId;
    var respFunc = function(par1,par2,par3,par4) { postUpdateInteractionNotesResponseHandler(par1,par2,par3,par4); };
    var errorFunc = function(reqId) { return showErrorCaseHandler(reqId); };
    ajaxPostRequest("Interactions.php",formData,"Update Interaction Notes.","subExtra",respFunc,errorFunc);
}
```

Updating the notes works at it should, but when trying to update it for the second time I get an error in Firebug: `unterminated string literal: saveInteractionInfo('Test`, where saveInteractionInfo is the function I am passing the notes to and 'Test' is the form value. So the error occurs when the newline is passed to the function.

Any suggestions how I could get this working?

*UPDATE* So the problem is that the $oldNote has line breaks (\n) in it, which stops it from passing the data to the javascript function.
The tag now:

```
<input class='button' type='button' id='Save' name='saveInteraction' onclick="saveInteractionInfo('fdsfsfsf
dfdfdf
gdfgdg', '13/09/2011 16:11:13', 'blaha01', '7038245', '2');" value='Update'/>
```

The tag as it should be:

```
<input class='button' type='button' id='Save' name='saveInteraction' onclick="saveInteractionInfo('fdsfsfsfdfdfdfgdfgdg', '13/09/2011 16:11:13', 'blaha01', '7038245', '2');" value='Update'/>
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Please post the code around that function call. I'm 97.3081% sure there is a typo somewhere around that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was similar to the one posted by **Rob W**:

```
$oldNote = str_replace("\r\n", "\\n", $oldNote);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the newlines by `\\n` using an RE, in PHP:

```
$oldNote = preg_replace('/\n/g', "\\n", $oldNote);
```

*EDIT*
Did you already handle characters such as '>' and '&'? If not, also use `$oldNote = htmlentities($oldNote);`. Otherwise, a `"` will break your code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one or more of your PHP variables ($oldNote eg) has a single quote in it.  When you write out the javascript you get:

```
onclick=\"saveInteractionInfo('Test''
```

Which would cause the JS to be invalid.

Suggest you change the onclick to take the single quote and wrap the php vars in \":

```
onclick='saveInteractionInfo(\"$oldNote\", ...
```

Comment: No, that's not it. There are no special characters at all in "Test", which is one of the values I've tried.